# How do I turn off preprocessing in pulp?

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, pulp, cbc

there is an inbuilt preprocessing in CBC solver , which affects the optimality of my solution , I get the optimal output by turning this off in command prompt . How do I turn this off using pulp ?

Comment: See my comment on anjikum's answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use **presolve** parameter and can pass it to solver(CBC) using following statement (model is your problem object)

```
model.solve(pulp.PULP_CBC_CMD(presolve=False))
```

Comment: https://coin-or.github.io/pulp/technical/solvers.html

Comment: This did not work for me. The presolve is still being conducted, and it led my LP to be 'infeasible.'

Comment: @ghjk Use `presolve=off`